# If $\phi: R \to R'$ is a ring homomorphism from a unital ring to another ring, if $1 \in ker(\phi) $ then the image is {0}

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> If $\phi: R \to R'$ is a ring homomorphism from a unital ring to another ring, if $1 \in ker(\phi) $ then the image is {0}

My thought is that:

If $1 \in ker(\phi),$ it means that $\phi(1) = 0$ where $0$ is the additive identity in R'

Take $a \in R$.

$\phi(a) = \phi(a*1) = \phi(a)\phi(1) = 0$.  So the statement is true.

Is this the right way to approach the problem?

Comment: Hi, in general we discourage posts that are "here's my solution: is it right?" (You may be interested in a [recent-ish post in meta on that topic](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29119/29335).)  In a case like this where you think you have a valid proof, it would be good to write your question and add "I am including my solution below." And then add your answer as a solution.  This allows the Q+A structure to stay intact, and allows other people to add valid solutions, and prevents "yes/no" from being valid complete answers.

Comment: Also please understand that the site is not supposed to be used as a pre-grading service for students. If you have no real doubt about your solution, you should probably not be posting the question-answer pair at all. But if you *do* have a doubt about the validity of some parts, it is fine to ask for verification of your thinking in those parts.

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly the right way to approach the problem. To be extra clear, you could include one more step and write $\cdots=\phi(a)\phi(1)=\phi(a)\cdot0=0$, but that really isn't necessary.

Comment: I added a few words to your answer. They weren't necessary, but I thought they made it a little bit easier to follow. :-) Delete them if you don't like them, of course.